# Storing multiple user input into an array

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program for a project, that asks for the user to enter the specific sport they want to play and their age for reservations at a recreation area. I am confused on how to store their sport and age into an array so that it can be displayed later in the program, if they select to view all reservations made by one or more users. If anyone could help me with figuring out how to store a single or multiple user input into an array so that it can be displayed later in the program that would be great!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char t; // Type of sport selected
    char g, G; // Gliding
    char h, H; // Hang-gliding
    char f, F; //Flying
    int a; // Age of patron
    double x; // Rates
    int s; // Selection from menu
    int i; // Arrays variable
    int num;
    char sport[100]; // Array for all sports of patrons
    int age[100]; // Array for all ages of patrons

    cout << "Please pick from the following menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add a new reservation" << endl;
    cout << "2. Print all reservations" << endl;
    cout << "3. Print all reservations for a given sport" << endl;
    cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    if (s == 1) {
        cout << "Please enter f/F for flying, g/G for gliding and h/H for hang-gliding" << endl;
        cin >> t;
        getline (cin, sport[i]);
        cout << "Please enter the age of patron, minimum age is 16" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        if ((t == 'f' || t == 'F') && (a <= 25)) {
            x = 68.95;
        }
        else if ((t == 'g' || t == 'G') && (a <= 25)) {
            x = 73.95;
        }
        else if ((t == 'h' || t == 'H') && (a <= 25)) {
            x = 99.95;
        }
        else if ((t == 'f' || t == 'F') && (a > 25)) {
            x = 55.95;
        }
        else if ((t == 'g' || t == 'G') && (a > 25)) {
            x = 65.95;
        }
        else if ((t == 'h' || t == 'H') && (a > 25)) {
            x = 92.95;
        }
        cout << "The insurance rate is $ " << x << endl;
    }
    else if (s == 2) {
        cout << "A patron aged " << a << " reserved a session of " << t << endl;
    }
    else if (s == 3) {

    }
    else if (s == 4);
    return 0;
```

Comment: I rather suggest you to store user input onto a file and while showing just read the file and show the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class Patron that contains the multiple informations, then make an array of type Patron instead of multiple arrays:

```
class Patron
{
    //data for each patron...
};
```

in main:

```
Patron patrons[...];
```

You could also use dynamic containers, like vector instead of an array.

```
std::vector<Patron> patrons;
```